# Optimization of the calculate of a new feature on pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I am trying to optimize the computation of one function on a pandas.
I have a simple dataframe with my functions (df).

There is another big dataframe with which I want to calculate a new feature for the df dataframe. At the moment, my code looks something like this:

```
  def func(x):
        df1 = big_df[(big_df['col1'] != condition1) & 
                     (big_df['col2'] == condition2) & 
                     (big_df['col3'] > condition3) &
                     (big_df['col4'] == condition4)]
    
        if df1.shape[0] == 0:
            return -1
        
        return df1['col5'].iloc[0]
    
   df['temp'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(x), axis=1)
```

I want to calculate of a new function temp.
Dataframe df has 100K lines, big_df about 500K lines. Can you please tell me how you can optimize such calculations on a pandas?
After filtering, I always take the first row and want the new column to contain the first rows.

Comment: So you're trying to add a new column that is 1 or True if all 4 of the conditions are true, and -1 otherwise, am I getting that right?

Comment: sorry, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

If it only contains `==` with `&` conditions, you can merge them.

1. prepare the big_df. Change `condition*_col_name` to the small df column names.

```
big_df = big_df[['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']] \
    .drop_duplicates(['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'], keep='first') \
    .rename({'col5': 'temp',
             'col1': 'condition1_col_name',
             'col2': 'condition2_col_name',
             'col3': 'condition3_col_name',
             'col4': 'condition4_col_name'}, axis=1)
```

2. Perform merging

```
dfr = small_df.merge(big_df, on=['condition1_col_name',
                                 'condition2_col_name',
                                 'condition3_col_name',
                                 'condition4_col_name'], how='left')
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry, not all conditions have == for me, I edited the question

Answer (score 1):

You could also do something like this:

```py
df['temp'] = np.ones(len(big_df))
for condition, column in <some list of tuples of a condition and a column>:
   df['temp'] = df['temp'] & (big_df[column] == condition)
df['temp'] = df['temp'].replace(0, -1)
```

For multiple types of conditions, you could add a few if statements inside the loop to implement different conditions. Eg:

```py
df['temp'] = np.ones(len(big_df))
for condition, column, operator in <some list of tuples of a condition, a column, and an operator>:
   if operator == "eq":
      df['temp'] = df['temp'] & (big_df[column] == condition)
   elif operator == "ge":
      df['temp'] = df['temp'] & (big_df[column] > condition)
df['temp'] = df['temp'].replace(0, -1)
```

This might be overkill if you're just always going to be doing 2 or 3 comparisons, in which case you could just list them out like so:

```py
df['temp'] = np.ones(len(big_df))
df['temp'] = df['temp'] & (big_df["column_1"] == condition)

df['temp'] = df['temp'] & (big_df["column_2"] > condition)
df['temp'] = df['temp'].replace(0, -1)
```

I think you're also maybe misunderstanding the use of apply in Pandas a bit. The way you are doing that apply, it operates over every row, but you really are using operations that could be executed against the whole dataframe. The x parameter in your function that you are applying would be a single row of the dataframe.

Comment: Ahh, just saw the edit about multiple conditionals